# angularjs connecting restfull webservice

Tags: angularjs

when i tried to connect local restfull webservice by using below code

```
/*Doesn't work*/ 
$http.jsonp('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall')
/*Works*/
$http.jsonp('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/angularjs-intro/collections/users?apiKey=terrPcifZzn01_ImGsFOIZ96SwvSXgN9')

    .success(function(data) {
        console.log('Success '+data);                
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error '+data);
    });
```

please tel me why it is not working

Comment: Please state what error you get. What is the RestfulAndAngularJS_Server? It is probably the culprit.

Comment: Is this a complete example? Are you resolving the promise for /rest/product/findall ?

Comment: I  am not getting any particular error  but it is going to error console which i have mentioned in the code i am using jersy restfull webservie

Comment: $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
                $window.alert('success')
                  }).

                  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                $window.alert('failure')

                        }); This is the code i am using to communicate to restfull webservice

Comment: any one can solve this issue  this is some what urgent

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs with restfull webservice communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579682/angularjs-with-restfull-webservice-communication)